# synchronization algorithm for cpfsk modulation

Tags: digital-communications, synchronization

I am searching for simple and efficient algorithm to implement in order to estimate the symbol timing offset for synchronization purpose

Comment: Do you have more inputs? Is it CPFSK of a given standard? Any perfomance requirements?

Comment: Impossible to tell without knowing much more about the system – timing synchronization is typically the most application- and channel-specific aspect of a system. For example, the things you can do under great SNR are very different from these you do under bad SNR. Now, in which regime are you? Hard to tell, but my guess "FSK" points to relatively bad SNR! Now, that screams for a number of possible approaches that are typically a combination of matched filtering and control loops. Now, which one you pick will depend on the number of FSK frequencies, and how well you've frequency-synchronized!

Comment: … and the list of inter-dependencies goes on. So, you'll need to describe the system you want to build (and that will quite likely also include a reasoning why you're doing CPFSK in 2022!) and what kind of performance you'll need, as in BER vs SNR, maximum / minimum frame sizes, and things like possible self-synchronizing channel codes etc.